# From $\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^2\cos\phi\sin\phi\sin(t\cos\phi)}{t^3}$ to $\cos^2\phi\sin\phi$

Tags: calculus, limits

> How do you go from $$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^2\cos\phi\sin\phi\sin(t\cos\phi)}{t^3}$$
>   to
>   $$\cos^2\phi\sin\phi$$
>   using L'Hôpital's rule?

I am trying to go over possible identities and possible steps. I just do not find how.

Thx for your input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^2\cos\phi\sin\phi\sin(t\cos\phi)}{t^3}$$
Trivially we can eliminate $t^2$ from both halves of the ratio and bring the $\cos\phi\sin\phi$ factor out:
$$=\cos\phi\sin\phi\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin(t\cos\phi)}t$$
Using L'Hôpital:
$$=\cos\phi\sin\phi\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\cos\phi\cos(t\cos\phi)}1=\cos^2\phi\sin\phi$$
Or the sinc limit (Lanzi, in comments):
$$=\cos\phi\sin\phi\cos\phi\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin(t\cos\phi)}{t\cos\phi}=\cos^2\phi\sin\phi$$

Comment: You do not need to use l'Hopital.   I would put $u=t \cos\phi$ and then identify the limit of $(\sin u)/u$ as $1$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi **DONE**

Answer (score 3):

HINT: it is $$\cos(\Phi)\sin(\Phi)\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(t\cos(\Phi))}{t\cos(\Phi)}\cos(\Phi)$$

Comment: The caps $\Phi $ is somewhat rare compared to $\phi$. Does make your answer stand out. +1